# How to use two different schemas based on a condition?

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

I have a `DatabaseConnection` schema with these attributes:
`db_type`, `db_connection_details`.

Now, for my flask app, I am supporting two database types: mysql and postgresql and I have two different schemas for both pertaining to the `db_connection_details` schema which have different fields.

Now, in the `DatabaseConnection` schema, is it possible to specify which schema to pick depending on the `db_type`. Thanks!

Edit:

An example input is like:

```
"training_data": {
      "source": "mysql",
      "connection_details": {
        "a": "",
        "b": ""
      }
}
```

`DatabaseConnection` schema:

```
class DatabaseConnection(Schema):
    source = fields.String(required=True)
    connection_details = fields.Nested(ConnectionSchema, required=True)
```

Now the mysql schema has `a`, `b` fields (as shown in the example), while the postgres schema has additional fields `c`, `d`. If the source is a mysql database, it should pick up the `MySqlConnectionSchema`, while if the source is a postgresql database, it should pick up `PostgresConnectionSchema` (in place of the `ConnectionSchema` field in `DatabaseConnection` schema). Is this possible in marshmallow?

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Sure, edited the post @Thomas. Let me know if any info you'll want to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subclassing the schema and dynamically selecting? Something like this. I haven't tried or tested it so just an idea.

```
class MySql(object):
     a = 1
     b = 2

class Postgres(object):
     a = 1
     b = 2
     c = 3
     d = 4

if _conn = 'mySql':
    SubClass = MySql
else:
    SubClass = Postgres

class DatabaseConnection(Schema, SubClass):
    ...
```